# Fetching reddit comments using JSONP in backbone returns HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jsonp, reddit

I am using the reddit API to populate models and collections in a backbone.js app.

To populate the collection, I've used a JSONP request in the sync method which works great:

Collection:

```
  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    var params = _.extend({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: 'http://www.reddit.com/r/gif/.json&jsonp=',
      processData: false
    }, options);

    console.log('fetching for collection')
    return $.ajax(params);
  },
```

However, when I use the same technique to fetch an individual link, the response is HTML and not JSON.

Model:

```
  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    var params = _.extend({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: 'http://www.reddit.com/r/gif/comments/1y1edn/.json&jsonp=',
      processData: false
    }, options);

    console.log('fetching for model')
    return $.ajax(params);
  },
```

Why does the reddit API return HTML for the model and JSON for the collection?

Comment: Have you tested the two links without Backbone ?

Comment: Try getting rid of the &jsonp= from your url. When I hit http://www.reddit.com/r/gif/comments/1y1edn/.json in the browser I see json. I'm not sure why your first request is working since it looks like a 404 in the browser. Does the reddit api require the jsonp callback function name to be 'jsonp'? If so, jQuery ajax already adds &callback= to jsonp requests so to override that you might try setting the 'jsonp' option set to 'jsonp': https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @mcbex thanks you nailed it. Removing "&jsonp=" from the url and adding it as an option to the query was the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been discussed in the comments on your question, but the error is that you're using `&`, not `?`, in the URL. You need to separate the query parameters (`jsonp=some_js_func`) from the URL path (`/r/gif/comments/xxxxxx/.json`) with a `?`.